# Javascript: why on one page document.write('id').style.display='block' works and on another not?

Tags: javascript, dom

I do not how can it be at all!!!
I have code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SHOW(){document.getElementById('11').style.display='block';}
</script>
<a href="javascript:SHOW();">show</a>
<div id="11" style="display:none;">Some text</div>
```

On one page this script works as it should be, and on another it doesn't work at all...

If this important I use jQuery on both pages.

How can it be?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the page contents? What are their html / xhtml headers and doctypes? Are they both validating agains't w3c?

Comment: Their header the same: <!doctype html>

Comment: I'm guessing there is other javascript on the page which is causing an error which is preventing your `SHOW()` function from firing. What's in the console?

Comment: It's throwing some error on the console?

Comment: I do not know how to check js console. I'm new in js

Comment: Is this the identical code used on both pages? If so, then you haven't shown us anything that differentiates one page from another. It would seem that the differences in the pages would be more important than the similarities.

Comment: You can use Google Chrome or Firefox (with the extension firebug), and press F12. Then check the tab that says Console, there you should see some kind of red message if there's an error.

Comment: In Firefox, you need to get Firebug. In Chrome, simply click CTRL+SHIFT+I in windows or CMD+OPT+J in mac. Click Console and refresh the page.

Comment: If I was to guess (since that's all we can really do here), I'd say that you're reusing IDs on the same page.

Comment: In console it's writes SHOW is not defined... But why?

Comment: *But why* indeed. We can't see your code.

Comment: It is a usual function I've defined on the top of the page with a list of others. They all work fine except this.

Comment: Baffles me when someone wants help, but isn't willing to provide the part of the code that *doesn't work*.

Comment: No, I do not hide code from you - it is just very large. So I shown the main part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said you're using JQuery, how about you use JQuery?

**CSS**:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<span id="show">Show text</span>
<div id="foobar" class="hidden">Some text</div>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$(function(){
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $('#foobar').show();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rdBkF/

Answer (score 0):

Vitali, you don’t need to use JQuery for something that easy, it is just wasting resources for no reason.

The problem of the code you just gave is that the ID of the element is “11”, and ID attributes should always start with a character or underscore, never with a number.

It might work in some browsers and in others might not.

My recommendation, use an ID that begins with underscode or an a-z or A-Z character and once the page has been loaded, register an event listener to the A element.

```
window.addEventListener('load',
function()
{
    elementA   = document.getElemenById('IDOfTheelementA');
    elementDiv = document.getElemenById('IDOfTheelementDiv');
    elementA.addEventListener('click',
        function() { elementDiv.style.display = 'block'; },
        true);
}, true);
```

Comment: @PHPBree why not? If you could explain why not, it would be more credible.

Comment: Because it was established in the question comments that even though a DOM element which has `id="11"` is bad practice, it works fine. The only browser that might have issues is IE and your answer suggests using `addEventListener` which won't work in IE anyway since it uses `attachEvent`. You also suggest to avoid JQuery for something easy and then suggest adding an event listener, when the primary difference between JavaScript and JScript is the handling of events which is normalized by JQuery.

Comment: @PHPBree OK, for a while I forgot that its always dangerous to mess with jQuery fanboys.